# Android XML Parse Exception

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file from the web.

I get the first few elements, and it's ok, but then on the Description one, the value contains Portuguese charecters, which throws the following error...

```
12-23 10:24:22.529: I/System.out(10924): XML Pasing Excpetion = org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 2, column 543: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

The error points to the " ó " charecter from the word "memórias" (memories).
I was reading around here about changing the encode type but it doesn't seem to affect the values.

How can I bypass this? I have no control over the xml file by the way.

If you can and are willing to try: here's the link for the xml:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/rc-cadernetadecromos?format=xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below link I think it is help you...

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/how-to-prase-xml-when-the-encoding-is-not-utf8-t7564.html

Comment: OMG! I had everything I needed (the same as they state there). I changed my code from the tutorial, but I was still using the old object instead of the new one with encode type set to ISO-8859-1. Your comment helped me noticing my problem. Thank you!